# @tanstack/solid-query + Suspense unnecessarily recreates elements

Tags: solid-js

I have a simple Solid component that fetches data using Solid Query:

```
function Data() {
  const query = createQuery(
    () => ["example-key"],
    () => Promise.resolve("example-res")
  );

  return <div class="box">Response: {query.data}</div>;
}
```

Then I use it inside of a `<Suspense>`:

```
<QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
  <ErrorBoundary fallback={(err) => <div>Err: {JSON.stringify(err)}</div>}>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading</div>}>
      <Data />
      <div class="box">Another element inside Suspense</div>
    </Suspense>
    <div class="box">Element outside of Suspense</div>
  </ErrorBoundary>
</QueryClientProvider>
```

"Element outside of Suspense" does not get recreated, but "Another element inside Suspense
" gets recreated every time I focus the page (because solid query triggers a refetch).

Why is that?

I'm visualizing the issue in a codesandbox by fading in all elements when they are created:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/compassionate-tharp-lnqkm9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A7%2C1